# Ionic2 navController pop with params (CallBack)

Tags: callback, ionic2

I want to make a callback between two page.
In the page 1, i have this code:

```
  DataInfo= [
    {
       Price: 0,
       ClosePrice: 0,
       UpdateTime:"",
       DefaultPrice:0
    }

  ] 

GetClosePrice(i):number{
return DataInfo[i].ClosePrice;
}
```

i want to get the value of 'i' from the page 2, How can i load the function GetClosePrice() when the navcontroller return to the page 1 (this.navCtrl.pop())

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**`SOURCE PAGE CLASS`**

```
this.navCtrl.push(Page,
{
    data: this.data,
    callback: this.getData
});

getData = data =>
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let order of orders) {
      this.data = data;
    }
    resolve();
  });
};
```

**`TARGET PAGE CLASS`**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams)
{
  this.callback = this.navParams.get('callback');
  this.data = this.navParams.get('data') || [];
}

sendData(event: any): void
{
  this.callback(this.data).then( () => { this.navCtrl.pop() });
}
```

**`TARGET PAGE TEMPLATE`**

```
<button ion-button (click)="sendData($event)">
```

Comment: You need to be careful to declare the getData function exactly as here, i.e. with an arrow function (having no bindings to the 'this'). Declaring it as a method of the source page class did't work for me, as it was executed in the context of the target page class.

Answer (score 10):

I answered similar question in [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic2-navcontroller-pop-with-params/58104/31). I just used `Events listeners` to achieve this behaviour.

**MainPage-**

```
import { NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { OtherPage } from '../other/other';

export class MainPage{
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
                private events: Events) { }

    private pushOtherPage(){
        this.events.subscribe('custom-user-events', (paramsVar) => {
            // Do stuff with "paramsVar"

            this.events.unsubscribe('custom-user-events'); // unsubscribe this event
        })

        this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage); // Push your "OtherPage"
    }
}
```

**OtherPage-**

```
export class OtherPage {
    // Under some function
    this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => {
        // Trigger custom event and pass data to be send back
        this.events.publish('custom-user-events', myCustomParams);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted answer, especially if you want to do UI related callback in the pusher's view.

Comment: Best of all solutions the I've found so far, to fetch data while popping the second page and returning to the previous page. Perfectly working!

Comment: There is also a [supplied callback function](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-navcontroller-pop-with-params/58104/32) based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - [ionic2 pop with params](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic2-navcontroller-pop-with-params/58104/4)